# Pass function argument returns into one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that returns a content for each field (a form)

```
function fields( $content ) {

}
```

`$content` argument will return different content for each available field.
If we use this for example and we have three fields, I'll receive three separate emails:

```
function fields( $content ) {
    mail('example@example.com','content',print_r($content ,true));
}
```

I want to combine the result into an array and then send to email, I tried:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($content as $field{
    $array[] = $field;
}
```

but it will only put the content of each into a separate array, I know foreach won't be working because `$content` variable is not already and array, but I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: What is the type of $content for each field ?

Comment: @HossamMagdy $content will always return HTML content for each field, currently I'm trying to get the content of pre-populated fields to extract url later.

Comment: Why don't you run `fields($array);` ?

Comment: @HossamMagdy I want to make a call later to be able to call each content like this $array['1'], $array['2']...etc

Comment: What do you mean by "make a call later" ?

Comment: I need to merge the returns into an array to be able to loop through it when I need to, or call them as I want.

Comment: Ok, by using your function it will always return 2 different emails because $content is not an array -- @HossamMagdy

Comment: Using the function in my answer, if $content is not an array it will send __one__ email.

Comment: it doesn't because I'm using it inside a function that will return different instances of $content based on how many fields, so if I have 5 fields, I get 5 emails, meaning $content is returned 5 times by parent function -- @HossamMagdy

Comment: Would you share the whole code ?

Comment: @HossamMagdy it's a huge code, I need to make a simple example

Comment: @HossamMagdy 
`$content['2'] = "hello";
$content['1'] = "hi";

function fields( $content ) {
        foreach($content as $field) {
            print_r($field);
  }
}`

this is a sample of function that send data, I can't edit this but I'm hooking the above function to it through the framework I'm using, so now you have idea how the content is returned, now I need to turn it into array again after it was splitted in the parent function without touching the core function

Answer (score 0):

you cannot equate $array like that, you want to add contents to the array but here you are setting the content as an array. use

```
array_push($array,$content)
```

Comment: This will still return 2 different arrays

Comment: when i said content then i meant elements of content in foreach loop, i just didn't remember the name of variable

Comment: $content is not an array, I managed to fix this, will post the answer in a sec, my function is linked to another function that triggeres foreach loop on each filed

Answer (score 0):

Using the following function:

```
function fields( $content ) {
    if(is_array($content))
        foreach($content as $field)
            fields( $field );
    else
        mail('example@example.com','content',print_r($content ,true));
}
```

If the `$content` is array it will loop through it & send separate emails (that's what I understood from your question).

If the `$content` is HTML content it will be sent directly.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I want to only send one email with each result of $content combined in one array, it already send seperate email for each content

Comment: Then by running `fields( $array_of_content );` where the function is as in your question, it should sent only one email message with all contents at once.